# SPARQL/GEPHI query to get musical genre related to each other

Tags: sparql, gephi

The website:

http://blog.ouseful.info/2012/07/04/mapping-related-musical-genres-on-wikipediadbpedia-with-gephi/

provides a SPARQL/GEPHI query to get all musical genre related to Psychedelic music.

```
prefix gephi:<http://gephi.org/>
CONSTRUCT{
  ?genreA gephi:label ?genreAname .
  ?genreB gephi:label ?genreBname .
  ?genreA <http://ouseful.info/edge> ?genreB .
  ?genreB <http://ouseful.info/edge> ?genreA .
} WHERE {
?band <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic>.
?band <http://dbpedia.org/property/background> "group_or_band"@en.
?band <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre> ?genreA.
?band <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre> ?genreB.
?genreA rdfs:label ?genreAname.
?genreB rdfs:label ?genreBname.
FILTER(?genreA != ?genreB && langMatches(lang(?genreAname), "en")  && langMatches(lang(?genreBname), "en"))
}
```

When I run this query on GEPHI's Semantic Web Import tool, I do not get any results.

What would be a correct query to get all musical genres related to a given musical genre in GEPHI?

Answer (score 1):

The example is quite old. The problem is that the resource http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic is only a redirect and thus does not contain the information you're asking for directly. If you use http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelia instead, it should work.